# android - How to draw only the sprite from an image on the canvas

Tags: java, android, image, sprite

this is the first time for me here, so I hope I'm doing this right :)

My question is the following: how do I draw the sprite from an image on the canvas, so that I don't get the entire (squared) image to show, but only the parts of the image I want (= the sprite). For example, I have an image of a robot on a white background and I only want to see the robot, and not the white background.

I hope someone here can help me with this problem, because it's giving me headaches of not knowing how to do it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the image and make the background transparent.

Comment: nvm I found the answer myself, turns out that you can just make an image transparent and save it as a .png file, then it works just fine :P